# Deep link does not work with Branch

Tags: android, deep-linking, twitter-fabric, branch.io, deeplink

This is what I got in my Manifest:

```
<activity
     android:name=".activities.VidyoSampleActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
     <intent-filter>
         <data android:scheme="facetalk" android:host="open"/>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     </intent-filter>
 </activity>
<receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_live_hjyeOhAByhF1x452yXtuEjdpCzhMiEAB" />
<meta-data
android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
android:value="c13e89c059c32c08041932f2d48b4e5bf1054b4a" />
```

I am using this version: `compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+'`

And I do in my Application class the initialization.
This is the url scheme I have set on my dashboard.branch.io: `facetalk://`

But when I try this link:

`facetalk://facetalk.vidyo-nl.com/mobile.html?key=saETMuvxjeW2akgzbyt46Xffio&guestname=Test123&secure=yes`
It does nothing.

Why is that?
I even created the code for branch from the Fabric AndroidStudio plugin. and it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
Let me know if more info is needed

PS: If I remove from the intent filter this:

```
 android:host="open"
```

It will work. But I don't think it goes via branch like that. cause it doesn't enter this:

```
    Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
    branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
            if (error == null) {
                Log.i("BranchConfigTest", "deep link data: " + referringParams.toString());
            }
        }
    }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
```

After adding some logs. I found out that this is getting logged, when the app starts the first time:

```
11-16 12:18:45.237: I/BranchConfigTest(25065): deep link data: {"+is_first_session":false,"+clicked_branch_link":true,"room":"DpoxihjuKKKE24FAP2ByTILdZsg","guestname":"John","secure":"true","$marketing_title":"Join Conference","$one_time_use":false,"~creation_source":1,"~feature":"marketing","~id":"325753563785928408","~marketing":true,"+click_timestamp":1479295095,"+match_guaranteed":true,"~referring_link":"https:\/\/facetalk.app.link\/join?room=DpoxihjuKKKE24FAP2ByTILdZsg&guestname=John&secure=true"}
```

I don't understand how this is being shown? Cause I just launch the app, I did not press any link.
Also when I press on a link I created, this does not get called anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Branch.io Integration shows that I need to add the intent as this:

```
<intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="facetalk" android:host="open"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But that did not work for me for branch 2.x. 
This was the way I was able to add the intent:

```
   <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="facetalk.app.link" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: This is actually not correct. What you have added is the intent filter for [App Links](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/guide/android/). The former is the standard [URI scheme option](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/). You need *both* of these for a full working Branch implementation on Android

Comment: The first one does not work like that. I modified it, took out android:host="open" and it works, but I do not know if it works cause of the normal uri scheme or it works via branch?

Comment: That depends...did you open a URI scheme address, or a generated Branch link?

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch.io here: you need to [create a Branch link](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/creating-links/overview/) and test with that URL. Directly entering the deep link path with the URI scheme is not the correct implementation and (as you discovered) will not work.

Comment: I created a branch link, from marketing. but if I try to open it , it takes me to chrome not my app

Comment: It's like it doesn't even recognise I have the app installed.

Comment: There are a number of reasons why this might be happening, and it's difficult to debug without more detail. I'd recommend submitting a ticket to the Branch [Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new)